# Lambda Expression: How to select from two non-related tables with one query

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, lambda, linq-to-entities

Would you help me to re-write this query syntax with lambda expressions?

```
(From Entity.Apple a in db.Context.Apples
From Entity.Bikini b in db.Context.Bikinis
Where a.Id== 10
Where b.Id== 15
Select new {NaturalColor: a.Color, FavoriteColor: b.Color }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I try to find specific records of two non-related tables, **with one connection**. In my example, next step may be this:

```
FindColorDiffrent(Naturalcolor, FavoriteColor){}
```

Comment: is there a foreign key between the two tables?

Comment: Not at all! There's no relation between Apples and Bikinis!

Comment: So how do you expect linq to join the 2 tables? You need to specify a join and the join condition between the first and second lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.Context.Apples
  .SelectMany(a => db.Context.Bikinis, (a, b) => new {a, b})
  .Where(x => x.a.Id == 10)
  .Where(x => x.b.Id == 15)
  .Select(x => new {NaturalColor: x.a.Color, FavoriteColor: x.b.Color })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```